# How to capture "any event" on HTML object?

Tags: reactjs

I have several HTML img element I want to manipulate on the following events:

onMouseEnter
onMouseLeave
onMouseDownCapture
onMouseUp

A naive solution (that works) is to implement these listeners for each event manually as such:

```
   <img 
      src={taskbarImage}
      
      onMouseEnter={(e) =>setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImageHover)}
      onMouseLeave={(e) => setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImage)}
      onMouseUp={(e) => setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImageHover)}
      onMouseDownCapture={(e) => setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImageFocus)}

      className="taskbar-application-img">
   </img>
```

This code is kind of messy and I would much rather simply attach one function that triggers any time any event happens on the  tag. After this, the function would then analyze for what event it is and act appropriately. Something like this:

```
const taskBarManipulation = (e) => {
  switch (e.type) {
    case "mouseenter":
      setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImageHover);
    case "mouseleave":
      setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImageHover);
    case "mouseup":
      setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImage);
    case "mousedowncapture":
      setTaskbarImage(taskbarAppImageFocus);
  }
};
```

The snippet above works for detecting the type of event and changing the variable. However, I don't know how to make the function trigger on any event happening in the  tag. Any suggestions?

Comment: `on any event`, you know that there are [a lot of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), listening to all those won't help with performance

Comment: So the best solution in a case like this is to have the events attached at the HTML element level rather than in the code execution? Is there then any kind of workaround to the bloat that would happen if I were to have multiple img elements with the same code execution upon the same listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), listening tho all of those will slow down your component, and is not recommended.

---

I'd use a function that returns the eventListeners you wish to add, and then apply that to the component using spreading:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const getEvents = () => {
    return {
        onClick: () => console.log('onClick'),
        onMouseEnter: () => console.log('onMouseEnter'),
        onMouseLeave: () => console.log('onMouseLeave'),
        // ...etc
    };
}

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 {...getEvents()}>{'Test me!'}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

If all those event have the same handler, we can create a more fancy `getEvents` function like so:

```js
const eventHandler = (e) => console.log(e.type);

const getEvents = (events = [ 'onClick', 'onMouseEnter', 'onMouseLeave' ]) => {
    return events.reduce((c, p) => ({ ...c, [p]: eventHandler }), {});
}
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

const eventHandler = (e) => console.log(e.type);

const getEvents = (events = [ 'onClick', 'onMouseEnter', 'onMouseLeave' ]) => {
    return events.reduce((c, p) => ({ ...c, [p]: eventHandler }), {});
}

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 {...getEvents()}>{'Test me!'}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise and effective answer. This is going to save a lot of redundancy!

Can I ask what the purpose of the spread syntax in the function call in the <h1> tag is in this instance?

Comment: @JSJB [The spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is to expend the h1 with the return object of getEvents. You cant just 'pass' the object, but youll need to spread it so it basically becomes `<h1 objectKey={objectValue} onClick={eventHandler} ... />`